# Implementation of a сoncurrent ValueTask<T> queue with return of job result

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task, background-service

I found an example of a job queue implementation on the Microsoft website.

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

**Example:**

```
public class BackgroundTaskQueueBase
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

    /// <summary>
    /// initialize capacity for background tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capacity"></param>
    public BackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity)
    {
        // Capacity should be set based on the expected application load and
        // number of concurrent threads accessing the queue.            
        // BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait will cause calls to WriteAsync() to return a task,
        // which completes only when space became available. This leads to backpressure,
        // in case too many publishers/calls start accumulating.
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>(options);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Queue new async task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="workItem"></param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(
        Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dequeue async task to run.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

And an example of a class of service working with this queue

```
public interface IService
{
    public BackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }
}

public class VisualizationService : IService
{
    public BackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public VisualizationService(BackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    protected async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.Info(
            $"Service started.{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Queue initialized.{Environment.NewLine}");

        await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem =
                await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Exception at {WorkItem}.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to get the result of the execution of `ValueTask` as I pass `ValueTask<T>`. Can you tell me how to rewrite the queue to be able to get the result of execution or maybe someone has a pattern to implement the `ValueTask<T>` background queue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you going to do with the result?

Comment: @StephenCleary
as a result of executing the asynchronous method I get an object which I serialize and give as a response to an external service request

Comment: If you need to save the response, then save the response as part of your asynchronous work.

Comment: What you are asking is painfully trivial IMHO. You can just replace the `ValueTask` with `ValueTask<T>`, and add the `T` as a generic argument in the `BackgroundTaskQueue` class and `IBackgroundTaskQueue` interface. I won't write an answer, because I find the class and the interface to be totally useless. They just wrap a `Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>`, which could just as well be instantiated and used directly.